# What is the meaning of 'scare eases' in this headline?

Tags: meaning, headlinese

Today I have come across the following [headline](https://www.premierleague.com/news/598233) on the main page of the Premier League website:

> Salah scare eases for managers.

I did not understand what the writer means by 'scare eases'. So I looked up the meaning of this combination in all dictionaries, but I couldn't find anything. What makes me confused is the word 'scare'. Is it a noun, an adverb or a part of a verbal phrase? Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to provide the source of your quote. If you read through the article (URL provided in the question) you will see the following text:

> Jurgen Klopp has eased fears of the Egyptian's absence for Monday's trip to Swansea City, with Salah having missed training this week.
>
> But the images on Liverpool's official website of the Egyptian returning to training on Friday means his 2.8 million owners are likely to retain his services, even if it is wise for them to have an active player on standby in reserve.
>
> Similarly, those managers looking to captain Salah will be careful to select a suitable vice captain.

From this text you should be able to understand what "scare" there is about Salah, and why it is eased.

The heading seems to be a bad case of **headlinese** - a style typically used in headlines, with a terse sentence that tries to capture the essence of the main text, but isn't necessarily a good summary, and sometimes isn't even a correct English sentence, strictly speaking.

Comment: The meaning is clear now. I really appreciate your answer; especially, your last paragraph. I had a feeling that this headline contained something strange. And you have pointed out that it's a kind of journalistic style.